AWS Personalize - ECOMMERCE MODELS
Is it necessary to separate PURCHASE and VIEW events into different datasets for training BEST SELLER and MOST VIEWED ECOMMERCE models in Amazon Personalize?
I have not yet tried to put the datasets together. I would like to know if in the case of BEST SELLER, Personalize filters only the PURCHASE events for training and re-training the model, or you have to set it or configure it somewhere.

Purchase and View events should be combined in the interactions dataset for the dataset group. Those recipes are pre-configured to only train on the interactions for the appropriate event type.

Thanks, James! Do you have any document or link where you can understand a little more what is going on under the hood?

The Personalize developer guide is the best resource: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/
